# Why do I get a referer to the HAL Browser instead of a JSON+HAL response by issuing a request to the root URL?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.0.RELEASE with spring-data-rest-hal-browser, spring-boot-starter-hateoas, spring-boot-starter-data-rest and a couple of other dependencies.

When I call

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM=" -G http://localhost:8080/api/v1 -v
```

on my console, I get the following response:

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x66a9e0
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x66a9e0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/v1 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.33.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM=
>
< HTTP/1.1 302
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=3DC642CBC288E944471DF289B11FBED4;path=/;HttpOnly
< X-Application-Context: application:dev
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< Location: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/browser/index.html#/api/v1
< Content-Language: de-DE
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 17 Aug 2016 06:11:47 GMT
```

But I was expecting to get a json object with all discovered resources. At least one, because I have currently one repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "billing-services", collectionResourceRel = "billing-services", collectionResourceDescription = @Description("Mandantendaten"))
    public interface BillingServiceRepository extends CrudRepository<BillingService, Long> {
}
```

Any hints?

Thank you,
Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [a bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-863) in the version of Spring Data REST that Spring Boot 1.4.0 uses. It's already been fixed in the latest Spring Data REST and Spring Boot snapshots.

You can try it out either by using Spring Boot 1.4.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT or by using Spring Boot 1.4.0.RELEASE and overriding the `spring-data-releasetrain.version` property to have the value `Hopper-BUILD-SNAPSHOT`. In both cases the snapshots are available from https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot.